# passing cloud front custom domain URL to lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a custom domain URL (my-custom-domain.com), and the REST API supports query and path parameters.

https://my-custom-domain.com/hello

https://my-custom-domain.com?firstparam=abc&secondparam=def

The invoked lambda has to return the response with some path/query parameters appended to the custom domain URL in json body. Basically the other resources which can be accessed.

Example: 
https://my-custom-domain.com/hellofromlambda1123

https://my-custom-domain.com?firstparam=abc&secondparam=yourblogpage&pagenumber=30

An Ideal usecase is pagination, where I have to give the previous and next links. How do I pass the custom domain URL to my lambda. 
I am working on node js 8

In conventional JAVA programming we can achieve this by HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL().
What is the way to get the custom Domain URL. I have enabled Headers for DefaultCacheBehavior. The host in the lambda event gives the API gateway URL. Is there a way to get the mapping of the Custom Domain inside lambda?

My Cloud Formation Template for custom domain looks like this

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Custom domain template

Parameters:
  ServiceName:
    Description: Name of the Service
    Type: String
  DeploymentEnv:
    Default: dev
    Description: The environment this stack is being deployed to.
    Type: String
  CertificateId:
    Description: SSL Certificate Id
    Type: String
  DomainName:
    Description: Name of the custom domain
    Type: String
  HostedZoneId:
    Description: Id of the hosted zone
    Type: String

Resources:
  APIDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - DomainName:  
            Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "InvokeURL-${DeploymentEnv}"
          Id: !Sub 'Custom-Domain-${DeploymentEnv}'
          CustomOriginConfig:
            OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
            OriginSSLProtocols: [TLSv1.2]
        Enabled: 'true'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
          - DELETE
          - GET
          - HEAD
          - OPTIONS
          - PATCH
          - POST
          - PUT
          DefaultTTL: 0
          TargetOriginId: !Sub 'Custom-Domain-${DeploymentEnv}'
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'true'
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
            Headers:
              - 'Accept'
              - 'api-version'
              - 'Authorization'
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
        Aliases:
          - !Sub '${DomainName}'
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Sub '${CertificateId}'
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
          MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2_2018
  APIDNSRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    DependsOn: "APIDistribution"
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Sub '${HostedZoneId}'
      Comment: DNS name for the custom distribution.
      Name: !Sub '${DomainName}'
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt APIDistribution.DomainName
        HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
Outputs:
  DomainName: 
    Value: !GetAtt APIDistribution.DomainName
```

Comment: So the issue here seems to be that you are creating your own CloudFront distribution, and setting its Origin Domain Name to an API Gateway endpoint -- and, with this configuration, it is to 
be expected that API Gateway is not actually aware of the custom domain name.  While this is a valid configuration and sometimes a desirable one, is there a specific reason you're doing it this way rather than configuring the custom domain name in API Gateway itself?  The optimal solution may depend on your reasoning.

Comment: Yes @Michael-sqlbot the intention of having the cloud front aware is that, if we might want more than one routes for a given API Gateway, we would configure that in custom domain itself. Also, we would want to run all cloud formation using template files for automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @thomasmichaelwallace for pointing to [my post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84588&start=81&tstart=0) on the AWS Forum that explains a way to inject the original request `Host` header into an alternate request header, using a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger.  That is one solution, but requires the Lambda trigger, so there is additional overhead and cost.  That solution was really about a CloudFront distribution that handles multiple domain names, but needs to send a single `Host` header to the back-end application while alerting the application of another request header, which I arbitrarily called `X-Forwarded-Host`.

There are alternatives.

If the CloudFront distribution is only handling one incoming hostname, you could simply configure a static [custom origin header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html#forward-custom-headers-configure). These are injected unconditionally into requests by CloudFront (and if the original requester sets such a header, it is dropped before the configured header is injected).  Set `X-Forwarded-Host: api.example.com` and it will be injected into all requests and visible at API Gateway.

That is the simplest solution and based on what's in the question, it should work.

But the intuitive solution does not work -- you can't simply whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin, because that isn't what API Gateway is expecting.

But there *should* be a way to make it expect that header.

The following is based on a number of observations that are accurate, independently, but I have not tested them all together.  Here's the idea:

- use a Regional API Gateway deployment, not Edge-Optimized.  You don't want an edge-optimized deployment anyway when you are using your own CloudFront distribution because this increases latency by sending the request through the CloudFront network redundantly.  It also won't work in this setup.
- configure your API as a custom domain (for your exposed domain)
- attaching the appropriate certificate to API Gateway, but
- do, **not** point DNS to the assigned regional domain name API Gateway gives you; instead,
- use the assigned regional endpoint hostname as the Origin Domain Name in CloudFront
- whitelist the Host header for forwarding

This *should* work because it will cause API Gateway to expect the original `Host` header, coupled with the way CloudFront handles TLS on the back-end when the `Host` header is whitelisted for forwarding.

Comment: Thanks I achieved it using custom origin header.

Comment: Wow, that solution with the regional endpoint is really clever. Has anyone tried this and can confirm that this works?

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli thanks, I don't remember whether I ever tried it but there's no reason I can think of why it wouldn't work.  When CloudFront sees that the `Host` header is whitelisted, it uses Origin Domain Name to establish the connection but then uses the browser-supplied value for the `Host` header for TLS negotiation and passes that value to the origin as `Host`, instead of overwriting `Host` to match Origin Domain Name, which is the default behavior.

Answer (score -1):

When using API Gateway + Lambda with the [Lambda Proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) the event the lambda receives includes the `headers.Host` and `headers.X-Forwarded-Proto` keys which can be concatenated to build the full request url.

For example for `https://my-custom-domain.com/hellofromlambda1123`

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Host": "my-custom-domain.com"
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi the "HOST" property has the API Gateway URL. But I need the Custom Domain URL. Is there a way to find the Custom Domain URL using the API Gateway URL?

Comment: Have you checked that? We use base path mapping to get a custom domain url and `Host` is the correct domain...

Comment: Yes I have :) The "host" is the API Gateway URL. The custom Domain URL generated in the AWS CloudFront is not coming in "host" :(

Comment: How are you providing your domain- are you using API gateway's basePathMapping?

Comment: I am using cloud formation template. From my API Gateway lambda I export the invoke url, and map it under cloudFront's cloud formation template under AWS::CloudFront::Distribution. Added the template in the question above.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you have a good reason _not_ to be using the built-in base path mapping from API Gateway- as that seems to solve your problem. The alternative would be to add `X-Forwarded-Host` as discussed here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=84588&start=81&tstart=0

Comment: The intention was to keep that custom domain logic out of API gateway so that if more than one routes are needed at anytime, we would deploy the cloud front alone. Also, using cloud formation templates for doing this.